# Unable to Display Database into a Table when Prompted to

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime-error

I was wondering if I did the code fragment below correctly? I can run it without errors but when I want it to show the fields in a "Table" format, it gave me the following errors.

```
public class EmployeeManagement
{
    static void display(ArrayList<Employee> al) 
    {
        System.out.println("\n   --------------------Employee List-------------------\n");
        System.out.println(String.format("%-10s%-15s%-10s%-20s%-10s%", "ID","Name","salary","contact-no","Email-Id"));
        
        for(Employee e : al) 
        {
            System.out.println(String.format("%-5s%-20s%-10s%-15s%-10s", e.id,e.name,e.salary,e.contact_no,e.email_id));
        }
    }
```

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '%'
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2748)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2734)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2671)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2625)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:3290)
    at EmployeeManagement.display(EmployeeManagement.java:43)
    at EmployeeManagement.main(EmployeeManagement.java:231)
```

Comment: It doesn't like the `%` at the very end of the first format string.

Comment: @greg-449 it works! but I got a new error: Cannot invoke "java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject()" because "ois" is null. What does it mean?